# Error " ... duplicate typename 'AuthorizationStatus' detected, can't auto-rename.." while using oapi-codegen to generate client code

Tags: go, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I am trying to use paypal's Orders V2 API  (https://github.com/paypal/paypal-rest-api-specifications/blob/main/openapi/checkout_orders_v2.json) to generate Client code using oapi-codegen tool. I get below error.

`hvk@LAPTOP-GH4L4EUD:/mnt/c/Users/paypal-integration$ oapi-codegen -generate types -o types.go -package main checkout_orders_v2.json error generating code: error generating type definitions: error generating code for type definitions: duplicate typename 'AuthorizationStatus' detected, can't auto-rename, please use x-go-name to specify your own name for one of them`

What is wrong here ?

I was expecting to generate client code for golang

Comment: Error message says to use an x-go-name attribute to give one of the AuthorizationStatus types a different (unique) go name. Have you done that?

Comment: What i see is authroization_status component has only 1 entry .. i dont know why it says duplicate typename .. There is another component name called as authorization_status_detailed .. Any idea why this happens ?